# How can I get a SourceLocation from a filename/line/column triplet using Clang's C++ API

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

The `libclang` C API has the following function for this purpose:

`CXSourceLocation clang_getLocation(
    CXTranslationUnit tu,
    CXFile  file,
    unsigned    line,
    unsigned    column 
)`

I can't find an equivalent for the C++ API. There are many `getLocation` functions but none that take this set of arguments.

I am ultimately trying to get the `DeclRef` at a given source location, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a `SourceLocation` for a file:line:column triplet can be done somewhat awkwardly through the `SourceManager` as follows:

```
SourceManager& srcmgr = astctx.getSourceManager();
FileManager& filemgr = srcmgr.getFileManager();
const FileEntry* file_entry_ptr = filemgr.getFile(filename);
SourceLocation loc = srcmgr.translateFileLineCol(file_entry_ptr, line, column);
```

I still do not know how to find the `Stmt` at that point though.

Comment: this may answer the question, but code-only answers are frown upon here. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations.