# Libclang: Get Symbol (e.g. function) at SourceLocation

Tags: c++, automated-refactoring, libclang, libtooling

I want to write a refactor tool, where I want to move the function at the cursor(cursor is in the function name) to the source file.

I found the FunctionMover.cc in https://github.com/lanl/CoARCT which is a good starting point to move the function.
However, I cannot find anything how to get the symbol (i.e. in my case function) from a file:line:column (or file:offset) combination.
I imagine this should be quite easy with the AST, SourceManager and libtooling of clang, but I cannot find anything about it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: not sure if i understood the question. Are you trying to get the function (functionDecl maybe?) from a clang::SourceLocation ?

Comment: I dont know if clang::SourceLocation the correct term. I have a file:line:column tuple from a different tool and want to get the symbol at that location (could be a functionDecl).

Answer (score 1):

I would try LibTooling, clang::SourceManager has a member function [translateFileLineCol()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#ac3cb8583909528664c0c982bcb1146e3):

```
SourceManager& SM = ctx.getSourceManager();
const FileEntry* FE = SM.getFileManager().getFile(filename);
SourceLocation loc = SM.translateFileLineCol(FE, line, column);
```

after obtaining the loc, you can maybe use [SM.getCharacterData()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a88ecde393b8281f7c0be5afdd0213624) or do other maneuvers.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359904/how-can-i-get-a-sourcelocation-from-a-filename-line-column-triplet-using-clangs) has a very similar purpose, I believe. Seems like there is also a solution with libClang.

Comment: Thanks, translateFileLineCol() is a nice convenience function, but I guess the tricky part is too get the symbol at that source location. printToString() just prints the file:line:column again. In your linked post, there is also no solution for this part.

Comment: @veio, sorry, i re-edited. does getCharacterData() from sourceManager work?

Comment: having said those, i wonder is doing so really more convenience than creating a for loop to iterate all chars ;)

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. I know what code is written at the source location (this is easy to get from just reading the file). I want to know which semantic meaning does the text at the cursor have. Is it a function, a variable, a body etc.